# Файл разметки для ListActivity и метод setContentView

Tags: android-sdk, android, listview

При использовании `setContentView` программа вылетает с ошибкой.
Я так понимаю, что `ListActivity` использует свой системный файл разметки.
Подскажите, как использовать другой файл разметки при работе с `ListActivity`?

Код:

```
  /** Called when the activity is first created. */
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.myListView);

}
```

Мой xml файл:

```
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  xmlns:android1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:background="@drawable/main_bg" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="65dp"
    android:alpha="0.7"

     >
</ListView>

<ImageView
    android1:id="@+id/imageViewCreate"
    android1:layout_width="match_parent"
    android1:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android1:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android1:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android1:src="@drawable/create" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

> To do this, your own view MUST contain a ListView object with the id "[@android](/users/664/androiddev):id/list" (or list if it's in code).

[Документация](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html), тут вроде и особых знаний английского не надо, чтобы понять.

Comment: Спасибо понял.

Answer (score 0):

Привет. Чтобы работать с ListView, ListActivity не обязателен. Покажу пример, как я работаю с ListView, надеюсь поможет:

```
package ru.mysamples.listview;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class ListViewActivity extends Activity {

    public static String[] TITLES = {
            "Title 1",
            "Title 2",
            "Title 3",
            "Title 4",
            "Title 5",
            "Title 6",
            "Title 7"
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ListView myListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        myListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, TITLES));
    }
}
```

Как видишь, я не использую ListActivity, а просто нахожу свой ListView в разметке и задаю ему адаптер. :)

Comment: Спасибо так у меня тоже все получается. Просто как я понял какой то функционал не будет доступен, какой я пока не вьежаю.

Comment: ListActivity упрощает подключение разметки со списком и содержит 7 дополнительных [методов](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html#pubmethods) заточенных под списки